# WebServiceContext not injected if @HandlerChain is used in the EJB exposed as webservice

Tags: java

```java
@WebService(name = "TEST_SOAPSessionWS", serviceName = "TESTSOAPSessionWS")
@HandlerChain(file = "TESTSOAPSessionWS-HandlerChain.xml")
public class TESTSOAPSessionWS implements TESTSOAPSessionWS,TESTSOAPSessionWSLocal {
    @Resource
    WebServiceContext sc;
```

Server used is Weblogic 12C

EJB Exception:

> com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Dependency injection failure: can't find the bean definition about class interface javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext; nested exception is com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext] is defined: No beans of type javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext; owner=com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Pitchfo`enter code here`rkGenericApplicationContext@3cc48cf7: display name [com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.PitchforkGenericApplicationContext@3cc48cf7]; startup date [Mon Nov 13 19:55:09 PST 2017]; parent: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@58681aeb
>           at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.applyInjections(Jsr250Metadata.java:224)
>           at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.inject(Jsr250Metadata.java:209)
>           at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.BaseComponentBrokerImpl.getBean(BaseComponentBrokerImpl.java:63)
>           at weblogic.ejb.container.injection.EjbComponentCreatorImpl.getBean(EjbComponentCreatorImpl.java:51)
>           at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.BaseEJBManager.createNewBeanInstance(BaseEJBManager.java:203)
>           at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.BaseEJBManager.allocateBean(BaseEJBManager.java:229)
>           at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.StatelessManager.createBean(StatelessManager.java:268)
>           at weblogic.ejb.container.pool.StatelessSessionPool.createBean(StatelessSessionPool.java:132)
>           at weblogic.ejb.container.pool.StatelessSessionPool.getBean(StatelessSessionPool.java:99)
>           at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.StatelessManager.preInvoke(StatelessManager.java:149)
>           at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.getBeanInstance(BaseLocalObject.java:148)
>           at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.preInvoke(BaseLocalObject.java:105)
>           at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.__WL_preInvoke(BaseLocalObject.java:70)
>           at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseWSLocalObject.__WL_preInvoke(BaseWSLocalObject.java:117)
>           at com.oracle.orion.km.services.ejb.EJBAdminSessionWS_avrnsg_WSOImpl.__WL_checkDocumentAccess_WS_preInvoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at weblogic.wsee.server.ejb.WsEjb.preInvoke(WsEjb.java:50)

Comment: Please add relevant code, if small enough.

Comment: Thanks. For readability, please add this to the question itself and not the comments.